# Posicionar elemento absolute respecto a un tr

Tags: html, css

Pues como dice la pregunta, necesitaria posicionar un `<div>` con `position:absolute` respecto a cada una de las filas.

```
<tr class = "danger" style="position:relative;">
    <td align = "left"><strong>&nbsp;<%=listaDatos.get(0) %></strong></td>
    <td align = "left" class="tdClave"  ope="<%=ope_actual%>" fl="<%=listaDatos.get(cabeceras_splited.length)%>" pl="<%=parametros_listado%>" tv="<%=texto_vuelta%>" pe="<%=listaDatos.get(cabeceras_splited.length)%>" tn="<%=titulo_navegacion%>">
        <div class="verOpcionesCelda oculto" align="center">
            <i style="margin-top:55%" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </div> 
        <div class="celdaOpciones">&nbsp;<small><strong>&nbsp;<%=listaDatos.get(j)%></strong></small></div>
    </td>                           
    <td align = "right"><small><%=listaDatos.get(j)%></small></td>  
    <td align = "right"><small><%=listaDatos.get(j+1)%></small></td>
    .....
```

Aquí el codigo de la fila, lo que me gustaría es colocar el `<div>` con `class='verOpcionesCelda'` de manera absoluta respecto al `<tr>`,

```
.verOpcionesCelda {

    position:absolute;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    height:100%;
    width:18px;
    float:left;
    left:-1px;
    top:0;
    background-color:#1c84c6;
    color:#FFF;

}
```

Este es el código del css, segun las especificaciones de la W3C, un elemento absolute se posicionara relativo al elemento posicionado mas cercano. Pero en este caso me lo pone relativo al div padre de todo.

La idea de todo esto es, que cuando haga click en dicho `<div>` este despliega unos sliders que ocupen toda la fila, por como lo tenia montado ahora solo ocupaba el `<td>` sobre el que estaba creado, la idea es ocupar toda la fila ahora.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano.

**EDIT: Añadido enlace a jsbin**

[Aqui](https://jsbin.com/vexiwed/edit?html,output) teneis un enlace a lo que hay ahora, lo que quisiera es que en vez de ocupar una sola celda, ocupara toda la fila.

Comment: Podrías con tu código crear un ejemplo en [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: has probado de introducir un `position: relative;` a los `tr`?

Comment: @Cheshire, como puedes ver en el codigo de la pregunta, esta puesto `position:relative` en los `tr`

Comment: Ya lo acabo de añadir @aldanux

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer requiere de un `wrapper` (contenedor) dentro de la celda donde se quiere mostrar el elemento en `position: absolute`.

Vale la pena mencionar que todo lo que se necesite mostrar en dicha celda, deberá estar dentro del `wrapper`.

**// UPDATE**

Para mostrar un *elemento* que ocupe **el ancho del tr**, es necesario usar `JS` ya que el elemento `wrapper` solo sabe cuanto mide el `td` que lo contiene.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('.cellOptionsBtn').on('click', function() {
    var $btn = $(this),
        $container = $btn.parent(),
        $td = $container.closest('td'),
        $tr = $container.closest('tr'),
        $msg = $container.find('.cellOptionsMsg');
    
    $container.toggleClass('open');
    if ($container.hasClass('open')) {
      $btn.addClass('fa-times')
        .removeClass('fa-eye');
      
      // Agrandamos al $msg tanto como el ancho del $tr 
      // menos el ancho del $td menos ancho del $btn
      $msg.animate({width: $tr.outerWidth() - $td.outerWidth() - $btn.outerWidth()}, 500);
    }
    else {
      $btn.removeClass('fa-times')
        .addClass('fa-eye');
      
      // Achicamos $msg a 0
      $msg.animate({width: 0}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Estilos nuevos */
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.verOpcionesCelda {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  left: 100%;
  top:0;
}
.verOpcionesCelda .cellOptionsBtn {
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height:100%;
  width:22px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color:#1c84c6;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.verOpcionesCelda .cellOptionsMsg {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(237, 85, 101);
  background-color: rgba(237, 85, 101,0.7);
}

.verOpcionesCelda.open .cellOptionsBtn {
  background-color: rgb(237, 85, 101);
}

/* Este estilo es solo para dar espacio a los costados*/
.row {
  margin: 0 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table">
      <caption>Optional table caption.</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td scope="row">
            <div class="wrapper">
              1
              <div class="verOpcionesCelda">
                <div class="cellOptionsMsg">
                  Opciones de la celda
                </div>
                <i class="cellOptionsBtn fa fa-eye"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td scope="row">
            <div class="wrapper">
              2
              <div class="verOpcionesCelda">
                <div class="cellOptionsMsg">
                  Opciones de la celda
                </div>
                <i class="cellOptionsBtn fa fa-eye"></i>
              </div>
            </div></td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Buenas @Marcos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero esto tampoco me sirve, el wrapper tiene el ancho de la celda, el efecto de sacarlo fuera lo consigues añadiendo margen negativo, y por estar el div en la primera columna, la cosa es que cuando yo hago click sobre el icono se despliega un slider que ocupa la celda, y mi idea era que ocupara toda la fila, voy a editar mi pregunta para añadir eso tambien.

Comment: @Hictus, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias, los sliders, se construyen dinamicamente y la cosa es que en cada fila puede a ver de 1 a 4 sliders, aunque no he usado tu codigo, me ha ayudado a solventar mi problema. Gracias!