# Posicionar un div en el centro de una tabla con CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo que colocar un div con una clase que lo convierte en un spinner y el texto "cargando" a su lado y quiero que se centre respecto a una tabla que está vacía... Luego se cargan los datos y éste desaparece. Al ser algo genérico, la tabla puede tener más o menos columnas y el div sólo puedo colocarlo dentro de una  ya que si lo coloco dentro de  se ve fuera de la tabla.

Encontré [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35454/posicionar-elemento-absolute-respecto-a-un-tr) pero quisiera saber si hay manera de hacerlo sin utilizar JS

Dejo el código:

```css
table {
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

th {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 3px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

th p {
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: black
}

td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    font-size: var(--fs-400);
}

table input {
    background-color: transparent;
}

table select {
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive-table {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.responsive-table table {
    width: 100%;
}

.spinner-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.spinner {
    border: 4px solid blue;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 10px;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}    

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
          <th>Acciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="spinner-container">
            <div class="spinner"></div>
            <div>Cargando datos...</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

La idea es que sin importar la cantidad de columnas que tenga la tabla, el div.spinner-container siempre se encuentre centrado dentro de la misma.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Ningún problema, al contrario.. gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al bloque de código del `spinner` podemos moverlo fuera de las columnas de tu tabla y hacer que su posición sea absoluta para que no afecte a los demás elementos, es decir, es como si el `spinner` estuviera flotando encima de los elementos:

```
<div class="responsive-table">
  <div class="spinner-container">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <div>Cargando datos...</div>
  </div>
  <table>
    <!-- Todo el contenido de la tabla -->
  </table>
</div>
```

Y le damos las siguientes propiedades:

```
.spinner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Aquí tu `spinner` ya era flexible, sólo le añado la propiedad `width: 100%` para que su contenedor ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla y esté perfectamente centrado. También le indico que su posición será `absolute` (como había mencionado antes) y tendrá un espacio por encima de `40px`, esto lo puedes personalizar a tu gusto.

---

Ejemplo con varias columnas:

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

th {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 3px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

th p {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: black
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: var(--fs-400);
}

table input {
  background-color: transparent;
}

table select {
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive-table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.responsive-table table {
  width: 100%;
}

.spinner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
}

.spinner {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 10px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}    

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-table">
  <div class="spinner-container">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <div>Cargando datos...</div>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
        <th>Columna 4</th>
        <th>Columna 5</th>
        <th>Columna 6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema que veo acá es que el spinner queda por fuera de la tabla. Igual se me ocurre que puedo probar a darle un alto específico a la taba para que simule estar dentro.

Comment: Puedes aumentarle su altura a los `td`, así simula que el spinner está dentro, prueba con `padding: 35px 10px;` al `td`, algo por ahí.

Comment: @Manu me avisa si esto es lo que necesita.

Comment: Discupa, entré justo en una reunión. Acabo de probarlo pero mi página tiene más información que sólo esa tabla y ésta no se encuentra el principio. por lo que el spinner se coloca en el parte superior de la página y no en la parte superior del div.responsive-table. Se puede solucionar eso? intenté ponerlo con position relative y bajarlo varios pixeles pero la tabla se baja también...

Comment: Lo solucione colocándolo después de la tabla y poniendo position relatetive y top -75 px y height 80px al <tr> pero no se si es la mejor forma de realizarlo... si hay una mejor forma soy todo ojos... Muchas gracias...

Comment: Ah claro, no tuve en cuenta que tendrías más contenido arriba, de lo cual tendrías que usar `relative` y ajustar el `top`, es una buena forma de hacerlo ;-).

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias ya voté y seleccione como respuesta al post. Saludos